# How to use relative path during uploading of File

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, image-uploading, sendkeys

I'm using Selenium WebDriver for auto tests. My current task is to upload a file.
I use the following code to get the invisible element and `sendKeys` there

```
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("profileImage"));
    String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible'; arguments[0].style.display='block';";
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, elem);
 elem.sendKeys("C:\\back.JPG");
```

I want to keep the file in the project folder. How can I use the relevant path to the file?

Both of the following methods return the Eclipse folder:

```
    System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Python:**

```
import os


picture_path = os.path.abspath("pictures/profileImage.jpg")

upload_input = driver.find_element_by_id("profileImage")
upload_input.send_keys(picture_path)
```

**In Java:** I did not test it, but I think this is a solution:

```
import java.io.File;


File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File picturesDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/pictures");
File picture = new File(picturesDir, "profileImage.jpg");
String picturePath = picture.getAbsolutePath();

WebElement uploadInput = driver.findElement(By.id("profileImage"))
uploadInput.sendKeys(picturePath);
```

If you compile the following code (javac ProjectPath.java):

```
public class ProjectPath {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

and then you execute `java ProjectPath` this will return the path of the directoy that contains ProjectPath.java file.

Comment: as I told before System.getProperty("user.dir")) returns Eclipse folder.. But my project is in another direction
so it doesn't work for me

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir") normaly returns the project's directory, not eclipse folder.

Comment: It returns D:\Tools\eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse.

But the directory of my project is D:\workspace\seleniumTests.

So it doesn't work for me.. why? :|